# Dynamic center div bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a responsive div list

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, from above i have four divs and when i only have 3 divs, they will in left

Is it possible do it dynamically when there is only 3 `div`  and they will be centered ?

If yes, how can i do that. Thanks in advance and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Centered you mean those 3 will be in the same row and is centered?

Comment: @Swellar yeah, that's what i mean

Comment: You say 'dynamically'. Do you add or remove the divs on the server or with jQuery? If so, you will probably need to add the appropriate classes based on the number of divs you are showing. You should be able to adapt the answer from @goose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To test, try removing a column.

For All Resolutions:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
 .col-xs-6:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
 .col-xs-6:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ .col-xs-6 {
     width: 33.3%;
 }
</style>
```

For Mobile Resolution Only:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .col-xs-6:first-child:nth-last-child(3),
  .col-xs-6:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ .col-xs-6 {
      width: 33.3%;
  }
}
</style>
```

Explanation:

```
`.col-xs-6:first-child:nth-last-child(3)`
```

For The column that is the first column, and also the 3rd from the last column

```
, .col-xs-6:first-child:nth-last-child(3) ~ .col-xs-6
```

and for all adjacent siblings of said column (every column that comes after)

```
width: 33.3%;
```

take up 1/3 of the width.

If there are 4 or more columns, or less than 3 columns, the first child can't be 3rd from the last, so we only change the width when it's 3. No flexbox needed (although I love flexbox), no polyfills needed, no bs.

Comment: what if there is only two ?

Comment: Then they'll each take up 50% of the row and stay centered. Is there an additional functionality you want when there's only 2?

Answer (score 2):

Try using a flexbox for `.container`. When using justify-content: center it will center it inside the "row".

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you can upgrade to Boostrap 4 you can do it like this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<style type="text/css">.col {background: #555; border: 2px solid #fff; color: #fff;}</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">column 1</div>
        <div class="col">column 2</div>
        <div class="col">column 3</div>
        <div class="col">column 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so how many `.col` that you add you will always get them centered.

Bootstrap 4 uses Flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, changing `col-sm-6` and `col-xs-6` to `-4` should give you the behavior you would like. If not, feel free to comment on this answer and explain how you'd like it to look.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `flex-container` with `flex-wrap` like this

```css
.my-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container my-container">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <a href="#">
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/250x250/000/fff">
    </a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem . Simple thing which i have add container-fluid class in div

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="col-lg-6">
 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-3">
   </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Try this it may solve your problem.